# How to find widest gap between jobs

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of jobs with (int)start and (int)finish times and (int)time range, find the largest gap between the set of jobs within that time range.

The gap has to be between all the jobs, so you have to check if there's a job in between a gap of two jobs.

I'm able to find the largest gap but I'm unable to figure out an efficient method of how to check if there's a job that conflicts with that gap without just brute forcing with for loops.

Comment: Just sort the jobs, and perform some sort of "sweep line" algorithm.

Comment: Can you provide some expected inputs and expected outputs